# Sementic-UI Modal is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, semantic-ui

How to write code for modal? I tried as semantic documentation but i can't get result.

I include:-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/semantic.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.4/components/modal.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/semantic.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.4/components/modal.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.ui.modal').modal('show');
});
</script>
```

Here is my code:-

```
<div class="ui modal">
  <form class="ui form">
  <div class="field">
    <label>Old password</label>
    <input type="text" name="oldpass" placeholder="old password">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="newpass" placeholder="new password">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="ui checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" tabindex="0" class="hidden">
      <label>I agree to the Terms and Conditions</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Please give some idea. Advance Thanks..

Comment: give an id to modal `<div class="ui modal" id="mymodal">` and do like this `$('#mymodal').modal('show');` but this will open the modal as soon as page loads and modal code is not DOM ready and if it's above HTML then it will not work so make it DOM ready too `$(document).ready(function(){ //Put modal code here});`

Comment: Thanks..but still i can't get the result. How to do when click button?

Comment: also i used click function still can't get the result.. can you write example code here?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

1. You're trying to get the `.ui.modal` before it's declared in the HTML. You must place the script tag before closing the `body` tag, but after all the other tags. Or you must use some `ready` event.
2. Your code has a sintax error. You must remove that `});` at the end of your script.

Take a look at the example below working:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.4/semantic.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.4/components/modal.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.4/semantic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.4/components/modal.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui modal">
  <form class="ui form">
  <div class="field">
    <label>Old password</label>
    <input type="text" name="oldpass" placeholder="old password">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="newpass" placeholder="new password">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="ui checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" tabindex="0" class="hidden">
      <label>I agree to the Terms and Conditions</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('.ui.modal').modal('show');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Buzinas..but still i can't get the result. I'm new to semantic UI.. How to do show the modal when click the button?.I done In bootstrape. but i need to show using semantic UI.